# React Error: How can i solve udefined errors?

Tags: reactjs

Here I'm trying to build an amazon like website. I build the login page. but whenever I refactor my code in a file then I'm getting an error. can anyone help me, please?

**Here is my login.js File**

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { userContext } from '../../App';
import { useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router';
import { handleGoogleSignIn, handleSignOut, initializeLoginFramework } from './LoginManager';



function Login() {
  const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState(false);
  // const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    isSignedIn: false,   
    name: '',
    email: '',
    photo: ''

  })

  initializeLoginFramework();

    const [loggedInUser, setLoggedInUser] = useContext(userContext);
    const history = useHistory();
    const location = useLocation(); 

    let { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };

  const googleSignIn = () =>{
    handleGoogleSignIn()
    .then(res => {
      setUser(res);
      setLoggedInUser(res);
    })
  }

  const signOut = () =>{
    handleSignOut()
    .then(res => {
      setUser(res);
      setLoggedInUser(res); 
    })
  }
 

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    console.log(user.email, user.password)
    if(newUser && user.email && user.password){
    };
      
        // ...}

if(!newUser && user.email && user.password){

  

  // console.log("submitting");

}
     
    e.preventDefault();   
  
  }


  const handleChange = (e) => {
    let isFormValid = true
    console.log(e.target.name);
    if(e.target.name == 'email'){
      isFormValid = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(e.target.value);
      // console.log(isEmailValid);

    }
    if(e.target.name == 'password'){
      const isPasswordValid = e.target.value.length >6;
      const passwordHasNumber = /\d{1}/.test(e.target.value)
      isFormValid =  (isPasswordValid  && passwordHasNumber);
    }
    if(isFormValid){
      const newUserInfo = {...user};
      newUserInfo[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
      setUser(newUserInfo);
    }

  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
{ user.isSignedIn ? <button onClick={signOut}>Sign Out</button> :      
<button onClick={googleSignIn}>Sign in</button>
}
    {
      user.isSignedIn && 
      <div>
        <p>Welcome {user.name}</p>
        <p>Email: {user.email}</p>
        <img src={user.photo} alt=""></img>
      </div>
    }
    <form action="" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

    <h1>Our Own Authentication</h1>
    <input type="checkbox" name="newUser" onChange={() => setNewUser(!newUser)} id=""/>
    <label htmlFor="newUser">New User Registration</label>
    <br/>
    <br/>
{    newUser && <input type="text" name="name" onBlur={handleChange} placeholder="Enter Name"/>
}    <br/>
    <input type="text" name ="email" onBlur={handleChange} placeholder="Your Email Address" required/>
    <br/>
    <input type="password" name="password" onBlur={handleChange} placeholder="Your Password" required/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit"  value="Submit"/>
    </form>
    <p style={{color: "red"}}>{user.error}</p>
   {user.success && <p style={{color: 'green'}}>User { newUser?'Created' : 'Logged In' } Succesfully</p>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Here is my loginManager.js file where I try to refactor my code for simplification

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import firebaseConfig from './firebase.config';
import login from './Login'

export const initializeLoginFramework = () => {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

}

export const handleGoogleSignIn = () => {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

    return firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then(res => {
      const {displayName, photoURL, email} = res.user;
      const signedInUser = {
        isSignedIn: true,
        name: displayName, 
        email: email,
        photo: photoURL
      }
      return signedInUser;
      console.log(displayName, photoURL, email);
    })

  } 

  export const handleSignOut = () =>{
    return firebase.auth().signOut()
    .then(res => {
      const signOutUser ={
        isSignedIn: false,
        name: '',
        email: '',
        photo: '',
        password: '',
        error: ''
      }
      return signOutUser    ;
    })
  }

  export const createUserWithEmailAndPassword = () =>{
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      // Signed in 
      var user = userCredential.user;
      // ...
    })
    .then( res => {
      console.log(res);
      const newUserInfo = {...user};
      newUserInfo.error = '';
      newUserInfo.success = true;
      setUser(newUserInfo);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      const newUserInfo = {...user};
      newUserInfo.error = error.message;
      newUserInfo.success =  false;
      setUser(newUserInfo)
          // ..
      // console.log(errorCode, errorMessage);
    })
    
    } 
    
    export const signInWithEmailAndPassword = () => {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in
    var user = userCredential.user;
    // ...
  })
  .then(res => {
    const newUserInfo = {...user};
    newUserInfo.error = '';
    newUserInfo.success = true;
    setUser(newUserInfo);
    setLoggedInUser(newUserInfo);
    history.replace(from);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
  });

    }
```

Here is what I'm getting:

```
src\components\Login\LoginManager.js
  Line 45:52:  'user' is not defined             no-undef
  Line 45:64:  'user' is not defined             no-undef
  Line 53:31:  'user' is not defined             no-undef
  Line 56:7:   'setUser' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 59:31:  'user' is not defined             no-undef
  Line 62:7:   'setUser' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 70:52:  'user' is not defined             no-undef
  Line 70:64:  'user' is not defined             no-undef
  Line 77:29:  'user' is not defined             no-undef
  Line 80:5:   'setUser' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 81:5:   'setLoggedInUser' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 82:5:   Unexpected use of 'history'       no-restricted-globals
  Line 82:21:  'from' is not defined             no-undef
```

Comment: Errors are valid. In your `createUserWithEmailAndPassword ` method, you have not passed any user so it does not know any `user` object. That's why it is throwing the errors. You need to pass that as props in order to use them.
Similarly, you have not declared setUser so it does not know what that is. These are simple mistakes you've made in your code where you are trying to access something which is not declared/present.

Comment: Where I can declare it?

Comment: If you're planning to use these methods outside of this file as general methods, declare them in those files and pass as props. Otherwise, if you want to do everything in this file, declare them here only like you've done in the 1st piece of code.

Comment: I'm getting error boss

Answer (score 0):

it's great that you split those method from the main component but you need to pass the state as the argument to the functions and everything will work it happend because it's on different  file and outside of the component
so it will not recognize the states so when you pass it it will work great!!
***UPDATE***
for example this one

```
export const createUserWithEmailAndPassword = (user,setUser) =>{
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      // Signed in 
      var user = userCredential.user;
      // ...
    })
    .then( res => {
      console.log(res);
      const newUserInfo = {...user};
      newUserInfo.error = '';
      newUserInfo.success = true;
      setUser(newUserInfo);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      const newUserInfo = {...user};
      newUserInfo.error = error.message;
      newUserInfo.success =  false;
      setUser(newUserInfo)
          // ..
      // console.log(errorCode, errorMessage);
    })
    
    }
```

when you call it you do

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user,setUser)
```

Comment: @TusarHaque here you go i put you a sample code

Answer (score 0):

Example:
This is your File A where all your general methods are defined

```
const method_a = (user) => {
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      // do something
    })
}
```

File B - here you will call that method

```
import {method_a} from "./fileA"
const user = // initialize user here
method_a(user)  //pass user as a parameter
```